# Object Variable or With Block Not Set (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Just in case it helps - I have had no problems with this macro for more than a year until mysteriously I woke up this morning and boom, it's falling over citing "Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With Block Not Set"(office update perhaps?).

This part of my code looks for today's date in each worksheet and takes the value of the cell next to it to show in a userform (tbProg, tbPlan and tbImp are all textboxes)

```vb
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Sh.Name = "Progress since last meeting" Then
        tbProg.Text = Sh.Cells.Find(sNow).Offset(0, 1).Select
        tbProg.BackColor = Sh.Cells.Find(sNow).Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color
        x = x + 1
    End If
    If Sh.Name = "Planned before next meeting" Then
        tbPlan.Text = Sh.Cells.Find(sNow).Offset(0, 1).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
    If Sh.Name = "Impediments" Then
        tbImp.Text = Sh.Cells.Find(sNow).Offset(0, 1).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
    Next
```

The error occurs on the line

```
tbProg.Text = Sh.Cells.Find(sNow).Offset(0, 1).Select
```

After a bit of trial and error, everything's groovy until I use

```
.Offset
```

or

```
.Select
```

or both, or any method at all.

Can anyone help me find a solution to this?

Comment: What happens if you use `.Value` ?

Comment: @Mikku same thing. I've so far tried `.Value`, `.Select` and `.Text` and all result in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens in your case is that you don't really find that `sNow` value, your code assumes that it should be there each time.

Also you don't need to use Find each time in that particular code, just once... try something like this:

```vb
    Dim rngNow As Range
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rngNow = Sh.Cells.Find(CDate(sNow))
        If rngNow is Nothing then Set rngNow = Sh.Cells.Find(sNow) 'Make a second attempt to find the date, in case is stored as a string instead.

        If Not rngNow Is Nothing Then

            If Sh.Name = "Progress since last meeting" Then
                tbProg.Text = rngNow.Offset(0, 1).Value
                tbProg.BackColor = rngNow.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color
                X = X + 1
            End If
            If Sh.Name = "Planned before next meeting" Then
                tbPlan.Text = rngNow.Offset(0, 1).Value
                X = X + 1
            End If
            If Sh.Name = "Impediments" Then
                tbImp.Text = rngNow.Offset(0, 1).Value
                X = X + 1
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print sNow & " was not found in " & Sh.Name
        End If
    Next Sh
```

Comment: Thank you @FAB - this has worked. Any final thoughts on why today it fell over after working for so long?

Comment: No problem, glad it works. Assuming until today you always had `sNow` value you were looking for there, so it didn't fail in getting the range.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've made a mistake here and marked this as the solution too early - sadly it only appeared to work because `Debug.Print` didn't stop the code and allowed the userform to show. I've just looked and the areas that I wanted to populate were blank as it's never getting hit = `rngNow` is always nothing, despite the `.Find` term existing within the sheet. It seems the issue lies within `.Find`. In case it helps, `sNow` is declared `Dim sNow As String` `sNow = Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YYYY")` and there is a cell in each sheet with the value "10/06/2019"

Comment: @TheBenetrator see updated answer... the date you have in the sheet is a number, you are trying to find a string... hence not matching. Keep in mind that if at any point in the spreadsheet the date will be stored as a string instead, this will fail as well.

Comment: aaah ok. That makes sense and I can confirm that did actually work this time - thank you once more. There are multiple other areas of my code affected by the same issue which I need to go and fix, I wonder why it's all of a sudden an issue today. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: @TheBenetrator I've added one more line in the code (see updated again), make an extra attempt to find the date as a string, in case is not being located as a date. There might be better ways to code this, but should do in your case i think.

Comment: Yep - that's made it more thorough. There were areas where the date being found was being treated as a string and other areas where it is being treated as a number - I have no idea why. Your updated answer caters for both and my code works again - thanks once more for you help